# How do I write code without a foreach loop?

Tags: php, codeigniter

How do I write this code without a `foreach` loop? I want to fetch the data from the database, but the key and value are stored in the database.

```
<?php
$options = get_payment_mode_options();
foreach ($options as $key => $value)
{
    echo isset($form_data["personal_info"]) && $form_data["personal_info"]->payment_mode == $key ? $value : "";
}
?>
```

`get_payment_mode_options()` is function in helper,

```
function get_payment_mode_options()
{
    return array(
        "o" => "Online Payment",
        "c" => "Cheque Payment"
    );
}
```

Comment: why dont u like foreach? it will be clearer then array_walk or array_map

Comment: I got the answer..."<?php
 $options = get_payment_mode_options();
 echo $option[$form_data["personal_info"]->payment_mode];
?>"

Comment: @Ann check below code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this,

```html
$options = get_payment_mode_options();
$paymentmode = isset($form_data["personal_info"]) ? $form_data["personal_info"]->payment_mode : '';
echo $options[$paymentmode];
```

helper function

```
function get_payment_mode_options()
{
  return array(
      "o" => "Online Payment",
      "c" => "Cheque Payment"
    );
}
```

Comment: this solution will works perfectly! except some case, if the `payment_mode` is not `o` or `c` , (such as `x`) it will raise an error 'Undefined index x'.

Comment: @Ann yea, rarely it makes problem. but I'm suggest for your code to improve :D . if 'payment_mode' from $_POST, $_GET, anyone guarantee it is 'o' or 'c'. I just comment for good practice. have a nice day! :D

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function get_payment_mode_options()
{
    return array(
        "o" => "Online Payment",
        "c" => "Cheque Payment"
    );
}

// make a new function
function get_your_result($your_key)
{
    if (!$your_key) {
        return "";
    }
    $options = get_payment_mode_options();
    if(!array_key_exists($your_key,$options)){
        return "";
    }
    return $options[$your_key];
}

// dummy for test
$form_data["personal_info"] = new stdClass();
$form_data["personal_info"]->payment_mode = "o";
$k = $form_data["personal_info"]->payment_mode;
// ~dummy for test

// echo result
echo "----".PHP_EOL;
echo get_your_result($k).PHP_EOL;
echo "----".PHP_EOL;
```